# Get back to the default terminal in debian

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, sh

I've accidentally press the key Ctrl + Alt + F1. It switches my default terminal to a virtual terminal, and I don't have the folder and user information in the command line anymore. How do I get back to the previous state of my Terminal?

Comment: Have you try Ctrl + Alt + F[2,3,4,5,6,7]?

Comment: Yes, but It switch to the black screen and ask for password, I've entered the root and user password but not ok. I restarted the system and found out that it's still the same terminal (1)

Comment: Hm... I cannot understand, what do you mean under "default" terminal? (I thought you mean terminal with X-server).

Comment: Well, I don't understand neither. In the default terminal, in the command line I have the name of the current folder and the username, but when I press Ctrl + Alt + F1, it switched to another type of terminal and I have just "$" in the command line. When I type cd /home/... the tab key does not work to help me to type faster. So I want to switch to the default parameter or type of terminal

Comment: Please, show `echo $SHELL` output. I think it's /bin/sh. In that case try to run bash. Thanks.

Comment: This may be the anwser, when I type $SHELL it shows nothing. So how do I run bash? in the shorkut I have only "Terminal" and it automatically points to sh...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17858/discussion-between-kulti-and-hoai-nam-nguyen)

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Alt + F7 usually brings me back to the X-Server, by default, the first X server runs on terminal 7, this same question has also been asked at [ask-ubunutu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157617/reverting-from-ctrl-alt-f1), some people report having to use Alt + F8

Comment: I've tried Ctrl + Alt + F7, it does nothing, Alt + F8 show me a total black screen! When I restart the problem persists

Comment: What build of Linux are you using?

Comment: I use debian 6.0

Comment: The more information you give, the better, what desktop are you using?

Comment: I use actually KDE

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + F7 is the correct key sequence to restore the X-Server for KDE, your keyboard is probably incorrectly configured, try using the 'xev' application to determine what the keypresses are mapped to

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kulti,
The problem of mine is the bash mode, I need to go to Settings->Manage Profiles-> change the name of the profile to bash, and it is just like before!